# Form not submitting after input button is changed with replaceWith

Tags: jquery

I have a form in which I click a button "Open" after the click, the button is replaced with a different button "Save", however, the save button does not submit the form.

```
$(function() {
    // activate a row
    $(".activate").live('click', function() {

        var rec = $(this).attr('rec');
        var status = $(this).attr('status');

        if (status == 1) {
            disable_attributes(rec);
            $("#activate_" + rec).replaceWith('<input type="button" name="activate" id="activate_' + rec + '" class="activate" value="Open" rec="' + rec + '" status="0">');
        }
        else {
            open_row(rec);
            enable_attributes(rec);
            $("#activate_" + rec).replaceWith('<input id="save_' + rec + '" class="update" type="submit" value="Save" name="submit">').submit_reservation_form();
            // add row to active_user_rows
        }
    });


    $('.clock').popover({
        placement: 'left'
    });
});​
```

Comment: live() is depreciating... use on().

Comment: @SableFoste "Depreciated" is deprecated in favor of "deprecated" :P

Comment: Issue isn't with `live`, it is with some implementation that doesn't seem to be listed in this snippet. Although it is deprecated as of  version 1.7, in previous versions it is not so it is not entirely true that `live` is *always* deprecated. There is a suggestion to use `.delegate` for older versions but it does not always guarantee a performance increase.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use `submit_reservation_form()`, but bind the selector for de save button to the jquery function `.submit("#yourformid")`

Comment: There are multiple forms using that 1 function so the .submit uses a class